# How to make HTML table copy-paste-able to Excel

Tags: html, css, excel

There are some very neat Excel like html spreadsheet options out there such as handsontable, but I am looking for something much simpler:

How can I change the html/css of a regular table, so that it can easily be copy pasted into Excel?

I am not looking for Excel file generator, I merely need my html table to be copy-paste-able.

Handsontable and wijmo flex sheet can do it, my question is: how do I need to enhance a regular html table to be able to do that too?

Comment: Not sure which version of Excel you have, but from 2007 and up there is a "From Web" option under the Data tab.  From there you can navigate to the page that contains your table and import it from there.

Comment: I should have been clearer: I do not want the user to have to do any kind of "from web" imports. Just selected the cells you would like to import, hit ctrl+c, go to Excel and hit ctrl+v.

Comment: What exactly is it doing when you do copy / paste?  Can you add the html of your table to the question description?

Answer (score 3):

> Example for google drive excel: this key word is '\t'

For me this worked. But I had to paste data from browser (Google Chrome) to **Notepad** and then copy them from Notepad to Excel.

Direct copying from Chrome to excel resulted in all data pasted in one cell.

Answer (score 1):

you need attention platform compatibillity.

Example for google drive excel:
***this key word is '\t'***

```js
var date = ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04'];
var data = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
var element = window.document.getElementById('table_data');
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + '<tr><th>date</th><th>count</th></tr>';
for (var i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + '<tr><td>' + date[i] + '\t' + '</td><td>' + date[i] + '\t' + '</td></tr>';
}
```

```css
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }
```

```html
<table id='table_data'>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, when trying to implement @lingyfh solution, the `\t` had no effect, I needed the `<tbody>` part which is not in the code but you can see it (AFAIS) if you explore the formated html in the snippet

So in my case what has worked is (here with `React`)

```js
                          <table>
                            {myarray.map(o => (
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  {o.secondArray[2].map(i => (
                                    <td>{i}</td>
                                  ))}
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            ))}
                          </table>
```

I can copy paste to a Google sheet without problems, couldn't without `tbody` regardless of having a `\t`